# Python function looping dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary

I'm trying to output employee information in a specific format.

dep_tup is a tuple with all the different department names the user input (no duplicates).

dep_dict is a dictionary with the departments as the key and the list full of employee dictionaries as the value associated with the key.

```
#Function that outputs the employees by department
def deps():
    for department in dep_tup:
        i = 0
        total = len(dep_dict[department])
        for i in range(len(dep_dict[department])):
            return "%s with %d employees\n" % (dep_dict[department], total)
            return "\n%s: %s, %s, $%f per year\n" % (dep_dict[department][i]["name"], dep_dict[department][i]["position"], dep_dict[department][i]["em_department"], dep_dict[department][i]["salary"])
            i += 1
```

For example, if the user inputs 1 employees from the sales department and 1 employee from operations, it should output something like this:

```
#Sales with 1 employees
#John Doe: sales lead, sales, $50000.00 per year
#Operations with 1 employees
#Jane Doe: technician, operations, $60000.00 per year
```

Comment: you can't have to consecutive return statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to print, once you `return` it returns what is to be returned and ends the function. Also you do not need to set `i` and increment it, as the `for` loop automatically does that.  The following should work (but i cannot be sure without being provided the initial input)

```
def deps():
    for department in dep_tup:
        total = len(dep_dict[department])
        for i in range(len(dep_dict[department])):
            print("%s with %d employees\n" % (dep_dict[department], total))
            print("\n%s: %s, %s, $%f per year\n" % (dep_dict[department][i]["name"], dep_dict[department][i]["position"], dep_dict[department][i]["em_department"], dep_dict[department][i]["salary"])
```

Comment: Yes that's perfect! I just had to put the first print line on top of the for loop so it wouldn't repeat that statement for the same department! But my dep_dict[department] is printing the entire list associated with that department. How can I just print the department name?

Comment: i would have to be able to see your dictionary to help